# PHP encontrar el primer carácter diferente comparando dos cadenas

Tags: php, string

tengo que encontrar el primer carácter de las siguientes cadenas:

cadena1 : 'football'
cadena2 : 'footboll'

y que indique la posición de la diferencia

He hecho esto

```
<?php
$cadena1 = 'football';
$cadena2   = 'footboll';
$pos = strpos($cadena1, $cadena2);

if ($pos === true) {
    echo "La cadena '$cadena2' no fue encontrada en la cadena '$cadena1'";
} else {
    echo " La primera diferencia entre las dos cadenas está en la posición $pos";
}
?>
```

Pero el valor $pos no me devuelve nada, alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Comment: Hola ¿Los valores (variables) los introduce el usuario? Y, para que te funcione el `$pos` tendrías que ponerlo así: `$cadena1 = 'football'; $cadena2   = 'ball';`

Answer (score 0):

1.- Lo que yo te recomendaría es que hagas un `str_split()` a cada una de tus cadenas, esto convertirá tu cadena en un arreglo con cada una de las letras que contenga por ejemplo:

```
$cadena1 = 'football';
$arr1 = str_split($cadena1);

$cadena2   = 'footboll';
$arr2 = str_split($cadena2);
```

2.- `$arr1` y `$arr2` son un arreglo con 8 elementos en su interior, cada elemento corresponde a una letra de estas cadenas.

3.- Entonces puedes recorrer estos arreglos y comparar letra por letra y si encontramos una diferencia guardamos la posicion en una variable ejemplo:

```
$posiconDifrencia = -1;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr1);$i++){
  if($arr1[$i]!==$arr2[$i]){
    $posiconDifrencia = $i;
  }
}
```

4.- Ya por ultimo validas si se encontró diferencias o no, ejemplo:

```
if($posiconDifrencia>=0){
echo "Se encontró una diferencia en la posicion ".$posiconDifrencia;
}else{
  echo "No se encontró ninguna diferencia";
}
```

5.- Puedes escalar mas el codigo y buscar si existen mas de dos diferencias mostrar esas dos posiciones, pero la idea principal, ya la tienes.